# Why opera browser does not render my website css correctly?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, autoprefixer

Hi I have my portfolio looks awful on opera, everything is messed up like there is no CSS on it
and I want to know why that happens.
Note: I used an autoprefixer that adds prefixes for all browsers (https://autoprefixer.github.io/)
I have added links to screenshots for my website on both opera and edge respectively.

my website: https://portfolio-yz.netlify.app/

opera screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLrch.jpg

edge screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJUzd.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem with the web-hosting you are using , we know you are using netlify to host your website.
try running your site on your local computer with some kind of server like xampp etc.

This will show if the issue is with your files or with the hosting itself.
if your site works similar as it works on opera, then the problem is with your files.
if your site works fine then you have to look after the webhosting your using.

Comment: I did so and the problem seems to be with my files, what do you think might causing this problem?

Comment: yes, as i said . Now to rectify your problem we have to look at your code base and css, i thing the problem is in footer section of your site, so look for bugs in html footer section (<footer></footer) an its relative div and css, if used. Since its your own site i recommend not to show your code here and rectify your issue yourself.

Comment: The footer is not the only problem but thanks any way

Comment: I figured it out, the problem is so ridiculous it turned out I was having extra brackets in media queries that opera and old browsers do not accept